# A fantasy novel of world split into the four seasons

Tags: story-identification, novel

The story, which I read around 2008, is set in a world where lands are split into the four seasons (spring, summer, autumn, winter). There are other lands that don't obey this eternal season setting but the book starts off in the seasonal realm.

It opened with the King of Winter (the king of the land of eternal winter) with his brother the King of Summer. After leaving the summer lands the third person perspective described the Winter King's journey through other lands and arriving back to his home. The king has dreams of a woman who has been kidnapped in a tower. The chapters change between the man's perspective and the woman's.

Comment: While you may not know when it was created, you may remember when you read it (as it has to have been created before that) this would greatly help us narrow down the book, also, if you haven't already, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details!

Comment: This stirs up vague connections to the Dreamers series by David/Leigh Eddings.

Comment: You don't need to tell us that you've made an edit, the [edit history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/190684/revisions) directly below your question will take care of that.

Comment: @Jojoblades Please [merge your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) instead of trying to suggest edits on your question posted by another account.

Answer (score 8):

Probably [Once Upon a Summer Day](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/285284.Once_Upon_a_Summer_Day) by Dennis L. McKiernan

Quoting from the blurb in the link:

> Borel, Prince of the Winterwood, has been dreaming of a beautiful,
>   golden-haired maiden night after night. He believes that she truly
>   exists-and that she is in terrible danger.

I have only read the first book, Once Upon a Winter's Night, in which there is the "normal" world plus the lands of faery, four of which are each permanently one season and ruled by a monarch.  Given the blurb above and other comments in the reviews, it sounds like the question relates to the second of the five books in the series.